# Discrete exotic 4-manifolds.

Tags: differential-topology, discrete-calculus

Exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a differentiable 4-manifold that is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^4$ and there is a continuum of non-diffeomorphic differentiable structures of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

But are they (PL) triangulated 4-manifolds that would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, meaning a topological space equipped with the “standard” PL structure obtained by a suitable subdivision of the standard cubulation, but not PL isomorphic to such $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Such discrete *n*-spaces are known from literature (cf. references to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_exterior_calculus) and since discrete calculus parallels the smooth theory, I presume that exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$ should be valid also for such a discrete 4-space (?).

Comment: It is very unclear what a "discrete 4-space" can possibly mean. And what would a smooth structure on such a thing mean either.

Comment: When adding this kind of clarification that is essential to the post, please click on the tiny `edit` to improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: Anything you can do to improve the body of the post is welcome, because as it is currently written, the post is unclear. You will often find on this site that comments (such as the comment of @MoisheKohan) are hints for you to improve your post by editing it.

Comment: Still totally unclear: What does it mean for the edge-set to form a lattice? What does it mean to satisfy discrete Stokes' theorem? What would it mean for such a graph to be "exotic"? For manifolds this means to be homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to some standard target. What can this possibly mean for graphs? At this point, I do not think you have anything close to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a (nontrivial) theorem somewhere in the vicinity of what you are trying to ask. The right objects to consider are *triangulated manifolds* (more precisely, [PL triangulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)), of manifolds, i.e. where links are PL spheres). (PL stands for "piecewise-linear," this is a generalization of the notion of a piecewise-linear function you might be familiar with.) Every triangulated manifold $M$ defines a graph (the 1-dimensional skeleton of the triangulation), but a triangulation actually contains much more information than that graph.

Every manifold admits infinitely many triangulations, provided that it admits one. Thus, the natural notion replacing diffeomorphism for smooth manifolds is the one of a PL homeomorphism. Equivalently, you can say that two triangulations are regarded as "the same" if they admit isomorphic subdivisions. Thus, one defines the notion of *PL isomorphic* triangulated manifolds. Now, one can ask:

Is there a (PL) triangulated manifold which is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^4$ (equipped with the "standard" PL structure, obtained by a suitable subdivision of the standard cubulation) as a topological space but is not PL isomorphic to such ${\mathbb R}^4$.

The answer to this is indeed positive and the proof uses the result about the existence of exotic differentiable structures on ${\mathbb R}^4$. The proof boils down to nontrivial a theorem (due to Kirby and Siebenmann) that in dimensions $\le 6$ the categories PL and DIFF are naturally isomorphic. In particular, if $M, M'$ are smooth 4-dimensional manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic then they can be PL triangulated so that the resulting PL manifolds are not PL isomorphic. From this, it follows that for every exotic smooth ${\mathbb R}^4$ there exists an exotic PL triangulated ${\mathbb R}^4$.

Comment: Would you please advise why would a triangulation of a manifold _M_, defining a graph, contain (strictly speaking) much more information than that graph?

Comment: @Szymon: Consider the complete graph $G$ on 3 vertices. It could be a triangulation of the circle. Or, if you add the 2-dimensional simplex to this graph (whose boundary is the graph $G$), you obtain a triangulation of the 2-dimensional disk. On the other hand, I do not have examples of non-isomorphic triangulations of manifolds of the same dimension, which have isomorphic 1-dimensional skeleta.

Comment: Indeed, but this 2-dimensional simplex (triangle) would define this (closed?) disc and would contain all the information necessary to reproduce it. It is only the fact that a disc and a triangle are _visually_ different that would support an argument that a triangulation contains more information than the underlying graph. Am I right?

Comment: @Szymon: My point is that 1-skeleton of a simplicial complex contains less information than the entire simplicial complex, that's all. In the example I gave, you have two complexes with the same 1-dimensional skeleton but of different dimension.

Comment: My intuition tells me that 1-manifolds that could be _triangulated_ by 0-skeletons (just a discrete space) are a pathological case. I am aware that they are formally OK; Stokes’ theorem reduces to the fundamental theorem of calculus, etc. Now, if you - just for the sake of this discussion - excluded 0-skeletons from considerations, would it still be true that a topological graph (1-skeleton) contains less information than the underlying triangulation?
PL triangulation seems to have a special role in the conclusion that for every exotic smooth ℝ4 there exists an exotic PL triangulated ℝ4?

Comment: Ps. I follow
[link]http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math22a2018/handouts/lecture33.pdf
where ℝn is replaced with a finite graph _G_ = (_V_, _E_), where _V_ is a set of vertices and _E_ is a set of edges.

Comment: @Szymon: In general, 1-skeleton contains less information. As another example consider the complete graph on 4 vertices: This can be either 1-skeleton of triangulation of the 2-dimensional sphere or of 3-dimensional ball. The text that you follow is too basic, you have to read something more substantial, including treatment of simplicial complexes, start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex. Lastly, for an exotic $R^4$ you will need an infinite graph.

Comment: Indeed, but you implicitly introduce continuous concepts such as surface (disc) or volume (ball). Otherwise vertices and edges of a topological graph are sufficient to define the topological properties of any _n_-manifold.

Comment: @Szymon: This is far from clear (and probably false) and, as I said, false is you allow for manifolds of different dimension. The only solid mathematical result available, I think, is the one I stated in my answer.

Comment: What is the minimum number of 4-simplices you need to create the smallest PL triangulated ${\mathbb R}^4$?

Comment: @Szymon Infinitely many.

Comment: But any discrete exotic ${\mathbb R}^4$ is created by a number of them. Is 4-simplex exotic?

Comment: A finite number of 4-simplices does not suffice to represent an exotic structure?

Comment: @Szymon Correct. Actually, you need Infinitely many simplices for any triangulation of a noncompact manifold.

Comment: @Szymon A single simplex is not exotic in any sense.

Comment: But you observe this exotic property via ${\mathbb R}^4$, meaning that you map one exotic 4-manifold to ${\mathbb R}^4$ and remap it back as some other homeomorphic manifold but loosing its differential structure in the process. Why would one need an infinite number of simplices to do that? Its the property of ${\mathbb R}^4$, not of he number of simplices. Right?

Comment: As I said, if you have **any** noncompact manifold (and $R^4$ is noncompact and any spaces homeomorphic to it is noncompact as well), you need infinitely many simplices to triangulate it. As a simple example, consider the real line $R$. Each simplex in the triangulation of $R$ is either a vertex or a compact interval. You need infinitely many of these to cover the line.

Comment: But how about Hauptvermutung (as stated in answer to Q3277909): “Let $X$ be a compact topological space which possesses a triangulation. We say that $X$ satisfies the Hauptvermutung if for any two triangulations $T,T'$ of $X$ there exist refinements $S,S'$ of $T,T'$ such that $S,S'$ are combinatorially equivalent”. We know that this is false for ${\mathbb R}^4$ and that there exist examples of compact simply-connected manifolds of dimension 4 with an infinite number of inequivalent PL structures. But anyway these topological entities considered are compact (?)

Comment: @Szymon: Some of these are compact and some (like exotic $R^4$) are not. The answer about Hauptvermutung is deficient in this regard and should be corrected. (I am sure that Lee Mosher knows that $R^4$ is noncompact.)

Comment: Incidentally, the discussion in the linked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277889/euler-characteristic-for-topological-surfaces-and-triangulations/3277909#3277909) was in the context of Euler characteristic of compact surfaces, which might explain why Lee assumed compactness in his answer.

Comment: @Szymon: Lee Mosher updated his answer to remove the compactness assumption.

Comment: You state that for every exotic smooth $ℝ^4$ there exists an exotic PL triangulated $ℝ^4$. I understand that this is equivalent to "For every exotic smooth $ℝ^4$ there exists an exotic simplicial triangulation of $ℝ^4$", as PL manifolds can be made by simplicial complexes?

Comment: @Szymon: Right (up to a minor language improvement).