# Showing the Euler characteristic is homotopy invariant

Tags: homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

> Show that $X \simeq Y$ implies that $\chi (X)=\chi (Y)$ for $X$ and $Y$ finite CW-complexes

Since $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent I know we have the maps $f: X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ such that $g \circ f =id_X$ and $f \circ g =id_Y$. How can I apply this to the Euler characteristic to show they are equal?

Comment: What is your definition of the Euler characteristic?  There are many definitions.

Comment: Euler characteristic being $ \Sigma^{n}_{i=0} (-1)^i k_i$ where $k_n$ is the number of n-cells

Comment: It will be covered in any algebraic topology textbook. Consider reading one.

Comment: Have you learned about homology or de Rham cohomology? Without something like that, it might be hard to prove: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1410974/2838